# How to store a mySQL query result in a C++ struct

Tags: c++, mysql

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
    struct Employee {
    int employeeNumber;
    char lastName[50];
    char firstName[50];
    char email[100];
    char phone[50];
    char extension[10];
    char reportsTo[100];
    char jobTitle[50];
    char city[50];
};
```

I am using these libraries.

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

I already have the successful query as I have tested it out on mySQL but now how do I store the result in the struct I mentioned above?

Comment: You're using C++ so you really should be using `std::string` and staying far, far away from raw character buffers.

Comment: I understand that but this assignment specifically asked for me to store the query results in this struct so I am confused as to how its supposed to work... Sorry if this is a juvenile question but I am new to C++.

Comment: That's very unfortunate about your assignment, but in any case first you need to read up on the [MySQL C++ Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/).

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL C++ Connector. You may need the following headers.

```
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>
```

As tadman commented use of std::string is preferable.

```
struct Employee {
  int employeeNumber;
  string lastName;
  /* so on */  
};
```

This helper function will come handy to copy the resultset to your Employee struct.

```
void copyResultsetToEmployee(const std::unique_ptr<sql::ResultSet>& res, Employee& employee)
{    
    employee.employeeNumber= res->getInt("ID");
    employee.lastName = res->getString("Lastname");
    /* so on */      
}
```

This is a used case:

```
bool getEmployeeFromId(int id, Employee& employee)
{
    if (!sqlConnected) return false;

    std::ostringstream os;
    os << "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE "
        << "Id = \"" << id << "\"";

    sql::SQLString cmd = sql::SQLString(os.str().c_str());

    std::unique_ptr<sql::ResultSet>res(stmt->executeQuery(cmd));

    bool present = false;

    do {
        while (res->next()) {
            present = true;
            copyResultsetToEmployee(res, employee);
        }
    } while (stmt->getMoreResults());

    return present;
}
```